# Converting UTF16 to UTF8 in MySQL

Tags: mysql, utf-8, utf-16

I tried to execute the following query

```
SELECT  Scania.GensetType, Scania.EngineType, Scania.Engine60Hz, Scania.Alternator, Scania.PriceEur
FROM Scania  
LEFT JOIN NordhavnGenset
    ON Scania.GensetType=NordhavnGenset.Alternator 
LEFT JOIN Generator
    ON Scania.Alternator=Generator.Alternator
LEFT JOIN Insulation 
    ON NordhavnGenset.Insulation=Insulation.Insulation
LEFT JOIN Klasse
    ON NordhavnGenset.Class=Klasse.Class
LEFT JOIN AirInletFilter
    ON NordhavnGenset.AirInletFilter=AirInletFilter.AirInletFilter
LEFT JOIN IP
    ON NordhavnGenset.Ip=IP.IP
WHERE (NordhavnGenset.MaxKva='46') and (Generator.Alternator='ECP34-1LN/4') and (Insulation.Insulation='F (90ºC/45ºC)') and (Klasse.Klasse='KRS\r') and (AirInletFilter.AirInletFilter='No') and (IP.IP='IP23');
```

However it appears that

```
Scania.Alternator=Generator.Alternator
```

have data type of text UTF 16 and text UTF8 respectively. As a result, it cannot be executed. I need to know the syntax that should be used for making this conversion

This is the error message I get when executing the query

```
#1267 - Illegal mix of collations (utf16_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`CONVERT(.. USING ..)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert) function to convert values from one character encoding to another:

```
Scania.Alternator = CONVERT(Generator.Alternator USING ucs2)
```

Alternatively you could look into why the column encodings are different and consider using either utf8 or ucs2 for everything...

Comment: To the anonymous user who tried to edit the answer to leave a comment: the answer does include an example. The comparison between `Scania.Alternator` and `Generator.Alternator` is a direct quote from the question. If you are having problems and can't find an answer that suits you, post a new question.